# SourceTree won't let me squash and merge my branch

Tags: git, commit

I’m working in SourceTree and I’m trying to squash commit a branch into another branch. I’m told I can squash by going into interactive rebase. So I’m trying to do that. I get this message:

[image: commit message]

If I just accept the commit message, it does nothing (I’m expecting the interactive rebase dialog to come up). My guess is that it’s trying to rebase from 93a74a2e to 93a74a2e onto 93a74a2e (i.e. rebase one commit into itself). Since there’s only one commit, it figures there’s nothing to do so it just ends.

The branch I want to squash is the blue one below:

[image: branch graph]

Is it because of that merge from the red branch right below the head that I can’t rebase (and therefore squash) anything before 93a74a2e?

What if I want to squash everything in the blue branch between a past commit (not shown in the branch screen shot) and the head, and then merge that squashed commit (ONLY the squashed commit) to another branch (also not shown)?

I’ve done this before on the command line like so:

```
git checkout destinationBranch
git merge --squash sourceBranch && git commit -m ‘squash merging from sourceBranch’
```

But it halts before it commits and asks me to commit it as a separate step. This resulted (I think) in seeing no merge in the SourceTree branch graph (I think it just saw the commit as changes in the branch as opposed to a merge). So I’m trying it through SourceTree this time.